# How to describe the specific cardinality constraints in e-r diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm learning database this semester. The homework on e-r model really confuses me.

The homework is drawing the e-r diagram about a vegetable market: A Vegetable Market has a collection of numbered stalls. Each stall has a name (unique) and sells at least one kind of vegetables (each kind of which has a name). Each stall sells each vegetable at its own particular price. Each farm grows some ***(at least one, but not all)*** of the vegetables, but a vegetable must be grown by at least one farm. Each farm has one name (unique) and address. Each stall buys each vegetable from only one farm at a particular price they have agreed. 

My question is that how to describe the constraint "(at least one, but not all)" in the requirement?
Another question is that since vegetables don't have primary key or discriminator, should they be treated as entities? Or should they be treated as somethings else like attributes?

Here's my answer: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [rrimg.com](http://fmn.rrimg.com/fmn056/20120919/2325/large_xnSN_416500023eb6125e.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Is there any diagram you drawn so far? Also, is there any specificial notation required?

Comment: I just upload my answer. We are asked to used the notation used in the book _Database System Concepts_.

Answer (score 2):

Ad.1
As far as I know it is impossible to place on a ERD diagram information like **at least one, but not all**, I would simply mark the relationship as **one or more**, which is possible. The only thing that comes to my mind is placing an appropriate comment, stating that requirement.

Ad. 2
Yes, **vegetable** in my opinion should be represented as a separated entity. If you wanted to place it as an attribute, you coud do this as an attribute of entity "Farm_grows", but you will not be able to preserve uniqueness, you will have to have some key anywas, and finally the worst thing is that, it wouldn't be 3NF.

My propositions is on the below diagram - unfortunatelly I do not have a tool that supports your notation (I know it would be possible to do it in Visio, but you shouldn't have any problems translating my notation to yours).

[image: Diagram]

The difference in comparison to yours is that I have one relationship for **SELL** and **BUY**, which is **STALL_VEGETABLE**. Why is that so? Because of this requirement:

"Each stall buys each vegetable from only one farm at a particular price they have agreed."

My model preserves that the Stall sells only those vegetables, that it bought, and also it because **stall_name** and **vegetable_name** are withing PK, it is impossible for Stall to buy one vegetable from different farms - your model allows that.

Comment: Tks for helping me solve the problem. your solution is impressive. I also learn the expresion of the relationship between two relationships through your answer!